# How can I see the PHP error log from Codeanywhere?

Tags: php, codeanywhere

I'm working with Phalcon using the Codeanywhere and I'm getting error 500 because of some changes that I've made.

My problem is that I don't know where I can find these logs.

Looking at the /var/log/apache2, I don't have access even with SUDO.

This is what I have at public/index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So any idea?

Comment: Is it a production site? If not; `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

> sudo yum install mc && sudo mc

And you will be root. Then view files as you need.

Comment: How do you know if the user runs a rpm based distro? In addition, installing mc for viewing the logs is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the logs as a user with more privileges. For example, running `sudo su -` and then navigating to `/var/log/apache2` will do the trick.